# Remove object particle with kivy condition

Tags: python, kivy

What I want is two things:
count the number of enemies on the screen. And remove all enemies from the screen with a contion.
The second chose is to allow enemies to shoot randomly

```
class Enemy(Particle):
    active = False
    tex_name = 'ufo'
    v = 0

    def reset(self, created=False):
        self.active = False
        self.x = -100
        self.y = -100
        self.v = 0

    def advance(self, nap):
        if self.active:
            if self.check_hit():

                self.reset()
                return

            self.x -= 200 * nap
            if self.x < -50:
                self.reset()
                return

            self.y += self.v * nap
            if self.y <= 0:
                self.v = abs(self.v)
            elif self.y >= self.parent.height:
                self.v = -abs(self.v)

        elif self.parent.spawn_delay <= 0:
            self.active = True
            self.x = self.parent.width + 50
            self.y = self.parent.height * random()
            self.v = randint(-100, 100)
            self.parent.spawn_delay += 1

    def check_hit(self):
        if math.hypot(self.parent.player_x - self.x,
                      self.parent.player_y - self.y) < 60:
            return True

        for b in self.parent.bullets:
            if not b.active:
                continue

            if math.hypot(b.x - self.x, b.y - self.y) < 30:
                b.reset()
                return True
```

What I want is two things:
count the number of enemies on the screen. And remove all enemies from the screen with a contion.
The second chose is to allow enemies to shoot randomly

Comment: What you want to do is probably best done in code that you have not posted. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish the first two of your questions by modifying the `PSWidget` class. By adding two attributes `enemy_count` and `killall` to the class:

```
class PSWidget(Widget):
    indices = []
    vertices = []
    particles = []
    enemy_count = 0
    killall = False
```

And using those attributes in the `update_glsl()` method:

```
def update_glsl(self, nap):
    self.enemy_count = 0  # initialize enemy count

    for p in self.particles:
        if isinstance(p, Enemy) and p.active:
            if self.killall:
                p.reset()    # kill this enemy
            else:
                self.enemy_count += 1    # increment enemy count
        p.advance(nap)
        p.update()

    self.canvas.clear()

    with self.canvas:
        Mesh(fmt=self.vfmt, mode='triangles',
             indices=self.indices, vertices=self.vertices,
             texture=self.texture)

    # reset killall
    self.killall = False
```

So, anytime you want the count of active enemies, just use the `enemy_count` attribute of the `PSWidget` instance. And whenever you want to kill all the active enemies, just set the `killall` attribute of the `PSWidget` instance.

As far as your third question, show us your attempt at coding that.

If you are using an answer that I gave in another question, where I suggested using the `on_enter()` method to start the game updates, then you can use `on_leave()` to stop the updates. The game movements are faster  every time you enter `MainScreen` because more updates are scheduled on each entry. Here is a modified `MainScreen` that handles that handles that issue:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    started = BooleanProperty(False)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        if not self.started:
            self.ids.game.initialize()
            self.started = True
        self.update_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.ids.game.update_glsl, 1.0/60.0)

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        if self.update_event is not None:
            self.update_event.cancel()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like your linked code has applied my answer

Comment: So now you just have to set `killall` when you want to kill all the enemies, and just get the `enemy_count` when you want the the number of enemies.

Comment: There is a problem. When you click on second screen and come back to mainscreen the speed increases a lot. When you leave the screen, the game movements must stop.

Comment: See my modified answer above.